# Using Simple form gem f.association gives NoMethodError for new action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, simple-form, simple-form-for

I am creating a website that allows people to post ads. In creating a new ad, I want them to select a category for that ad from a prepopulated list in my seeds.rb. So I've made the following models and associations.

app/models/ad.rb

```
class Ad < ApplicationRecord
  # validations
  belongs_to :category
end
```

app/models/category.rb

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_ancestry
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged

  has_many :ads
end
```

Then I modified my Ad form, using simple form, to use `f.association :category` to generate a selection from the pre-populated categories listing (See below)

app/views/ads/new.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for @ad, url: ads_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :title, label: false, placeholder: "Item/Service for Sale" %>
  <%= f.association :category, label_method: :name, value_method: :id %>
  # other stuff 
<% end %>
```

I continue to get the following error: "NoMethodError in Ads#new: undefined method `category_id' for #
Did you mean?  category
               category="

Any idea what the problem can be? Also, here's the new and create actions in my Ads controller:

```
class AdsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :create] 

  def new
    @ad = Ad.new
  end 

  def create
    @ad = current_user.ads.create(ad_params)
    if @ad.valid?
      flash[:notice] = "Ad created successfully"
      redirect_to ad_path(@ad)
    else
      render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end 
  end 

  # other actions 


  private

  def ad_params
    params.require(:ad).permit(:title, :cost, :description, :quantity, :phone, :email, :accepted)
  end 
end
```

Some help in getting this form to work would be appreciated!

Comment: Show schema.rb definiitions for ads and categories tables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you are missing the category_id in Ads table

Although an Ad belongs_to :category, if you have not set a category_id column on your Ads table it will not work.

If you need to add this column you should create a migration

```
class AddCategoryToAds < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :ads, :category, index: true
  end
end
```

This migration can be automatically created using:

```
rails g migration AddCategoryToAds category:references
```

Finally, allow category_id as a parameter:

```
def ad_params
  params.require(:ad).permit(:title, :cost, :description, :quantity, :phone, :email, :accepted, :category_id)
end
```

Comment: You were right! This did the trick. Thanks for helping a rails newbie :)

Comment: Well. It's strange you accepted the other answer, given that, although I know it's correct, mine is more complete and I posted it before :)

Comment: @Pablo that was an accident -- sorry and corrected now :) Your answer is accepted.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that comes to my mind is forgotten `category_id` column, missing from `ads` database table - especially since it's also missing from permitted `ad_params`.

Comment: Indeed you were right! Thanks for helping a rails newbie !